# Number of possible subsequences

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given 4 integers - $A,B,C,D$ such that $A \leq B \leq C \leq D$ (i.e they are in non decreasing order).

Now we need to find number of possible non decreasing subsequences $(W,X,Y,Z)$ such that $1 \leq W \leq A , 1 \leq X \leq B , 1 \leq Y \leq C, 1 \leq Z \leq D$.

Also, $W \leq X \leq Y \leq Z$.

For example - if $A=1$, $B=2$, $C=3$, $D=4$

We can have $14$ valid subsequences:

$1 1 1 1$
$1 1 1 2$
$1 1 1 3$
$1 1 1 4$
$1 1 2 2$
$1 1 2 3$
$1 1 2 4$
$1 1 3 3$
$1 1 3 4$
$1 2 2 2$
$1 2 2 3$
$1 2 2 4$
$1 2 3 3$
$1 2 3 4$

What is the way to evaluate this?

Comment: Not direct, but related to an ongoing contest problem - https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/may-world-codesprint/challenges/xor-quadruples

Comment: i guess this is way too different query than the question.. I have almost  completed it.. just need a hint to calculate this value if it's possible ... otherwise no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate this explicitly by writing it as a quadruple sum over $W$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$, with lower limit the preceding variable and upper limit the specified upper limit. You can evaluate the sums one by one using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).